# How to cancel all jobs from printer

Tags: network-printer

We have network printer printing through a server, but some times some user
tries to print the job locally instead of using the print server.

In case the localy printed job is wrong or incompatible it hangs the HP printer with 49.4C02 error and there is no way to track down who sent the wrong job and printer

At last the only option remains is to change the printers ip address which resolves the issue or if the user himself cancels the job from his computer.

Answer (score 1):

Most networked printers have an "access list" that specifies the IP addresses from which it will accept print jobs. If you only put the server's IP in that list, the only way to print to it is via the server.

To find the access list, browse to your printer's IP address and go through the various options under its network settings.

Unfortunately, some HP printers do not support an access list. In that case you can still get partial success by doing the following. First, change the server so all jobs are sent using LPR (under Port Settings in the driver). Then, from the printer's web page, disable RAW printing (aka AppSocket or JetDirect). When most users want to connect direct to the printer, RAW printing will fail and they will not think of trying LPR, as that is not the normal protocol.

LPR uses port 515 and RAW uses port 9100, so you could also disable port 9100 on your router to prevent anyone from using it.